# Slack: Bot name in sent messages

Tags: bots, slack-api, slack

I created a bot named "esmeralda". When I send a message to Slack with the token generated for this esmeralda, the message just appears to be from "bot", not "esmeralda".

Can I do something so that the message will be shown to be sent by "esmeralda" instead the "bot"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the Web API and therefore the [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) method?

I'm further guessing that you're **not** passing `as_user=true` as one of your parameters. Try doing that.

(If my guesses are wrong, please include the actual details of what you're doing: at least tell us what API you're using, what method you're calling, and what parameters you're passing. Ideally share code.)